# Autocomplete is not working Haystack with elastic search

Tags: python, django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I m trying to make autocomplete api for one model in django. First time using haystack with elastic search. Getting error while trying to get autocomplete results.

```
Failed to query Elasticsearch using 'content_auto:(Jitney)': TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'[query_string] query does not support [fuzzy_min_sim]')
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fun_fact = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    production_company = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    actor1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    actor2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    actor3 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "sf_movies"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

search.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from models import Movie


class MovieIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    year = indexes.CharField(model_attr='year')

    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Movie

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet


def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:5]
    suggestions = [result.title for result in sqs]
    # Make sure you return a JSON object, not a bare list.
    # Otherwise, you could be vulnerable to an XSS attack.
    the_data = json.dumps({
        'results': suggestions
    })
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

directory structure

```
.
── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── search.py
│   ├── template
│   │   └── search
│   │       └── indexes
│   │           └── app
│   │               └── movie_text.txt
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── uber_assignment_SF_movies
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── wsgi.py
```

movie_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.year }}
{{ object.production_company }}
{{ object.director }}
```

when i run rebuild_index command i get below output

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
~
```

what i am missing unable to find issue here.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake with search file name. I named file as "search.py" instead of "search_indexes.py"